# How to trigger autocomplete on a character

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, ace-editor

How to trigger autocomplete when "$" is typed and show only custom defined array of strings.

For eg:- var wordlist=["Java","Javascript","KNIME","Altreyx","Tableau"]

I need this list of array to show up when '$' is pressed or at very least when Ctrl+Space is pressed.

Is it possible to call Jquery textcomplete plugin or At.js in ace editor for this? or is there any other way to it?

Is it possible to detect any new word used with dollar and push to array of strings?
NEW$PYTHON<-NEW$JAVA[using autocomplete]

Now autocomplete should have "PYTHON" in list of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use afterExec event to not add a special command which wouldn't work for some international keyboard layouts see the following comment for an example https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3337#issuecomment-317277416